# How to Cast value of TimeStamp datetime into mysql in android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm trying to cast/get the value of DatePickerDialog **EditText "etDate"** into mysql database. the datePickerDialog works fine(i can open it and select the date n display it in EditText).

And i declare it as below (The Timestamp is **java.sql.Timestamp**:)

```
final Timestamp datetime = Timestamp.valueOf(etDate.getText().toString());
```

Above code , i add it inside **bRegister.setOnClickListener**

the code shows no error and apps can run, but when i click on **bRegister.setOnClickListener**, it shows error as below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: my.com.rozaimi.datetime, PID: 15786
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffffff; was '2016-10-6'
                      at java.sql.Timestamp.badTimestampString(Timestamp.java:507)
                      at java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:414)
                      at my.com.rozaimi.datetime.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse a date string when a timestamp is expected, and the error output is pretty clear about this.  One workaround would be to create a `java.util.Date` using your date string, then initialize a `java.sql.Timestamp` object using milliseconds since the epoch:

```
String dateString = etDate.getText().toString();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
java.util.Date date;
try {
    date = df.parse(dateString);
    Timestamp datetime = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The line

```
Timestamp datetime = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

uses the *constructor* of `java.sql.Timestamp` to create a timestamp using milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: Hi . thanks for the prompt response. your code above, i need to add it inside bRegister listener or inside onCreate method ?

Comment: Date in android has two type which are Date(java.util) and Date(java.sql) , which one is it ? thanks again :)

Comment: I don't know where exactly you need to add this, but it should replace your current one line attempt to create a `java.sql.Timestamp` using the date string.